# Crash When Swiping To Delete

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have several UITableViews in an app, and swipe to delete is working fine on all of them. The problem is, when I try to swipe over an empty cell (at the bottom), the app just crashes with:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:833
2012-03-24 16:20:03.158 [22339:707] Exception - attempt to delete row 3 from section 0 which only contains 3 rows before the update - attempt to delete row 3 from section 0 which only contains 3 rows before the update
```

Neither `cellForRowAtIndexPath, commitEditingStyle` nor `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` are called before the crash, its like the crash happens before any of my methods have chance to be called.

For reference, I have this in `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ((indexPath.row == self.insertIndex && indexPath.section == [self.sections count] -1) || (indexPath.row == 0 && [sections count]==0)) { // last row of section, or only row of only section
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is actually a huge problem, as the app is virtually unusable when the tableview scrolls.

Comment: What code do you have in editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I've added the code, but the app crashes before it's called.

Comment: If none of the methods are being called, do you have the delegate set correctly?

Comment: The methods are called, but not before the crash which happens when swiping an empty area. They're called as normal when swiping over a valid row.

Comment: If you disable the edit style completely, can you still swipe and crash on the empty cells?

Comment: Have a read of this. https://discussions.apple.com/message/8287973?messageID=8287973#8287973?messageID=8287973 same problem but no solution in afraid. Possible bug?

Comment: I still get a crash, and yes I did see that article but assumed it had been fixed since 2008. Shame on Apple if this is the same bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the root cause of this was trying to reload rows in the table view while it was refreshing. There must have been some kind of inconsistent state which resulted, crashing the app every time.

Comment: I just had this same issue. In my commitEditingStyle delete code, I call a method that deletes the row from the central storage object. The central storage object has a notification which posts on a delete to refresh all the tableviews which use the data. I commented out the [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:... line and problem solved. I'm not sure if this will cause some problem in the future, since now the tableview is relying on the data store to send that notification

Comment: I made another change. Just in case the central storage object logic changed and it did not send the notification back to the tableView. So I put the [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:... line back in and at the same time put a check in the notification call handler (which just called reloadData) to not reload if the table was editing, ie table isEditing = YES. Now if the storage object does not send that notification message, the tableview code wont crash on inconsistent state

Comment: Also applied in my case for UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//    tableView.isEditing ? NSLog(@"show edit controls"):NSLog(@"don't show edit controls");

    if(tableView.isEditing){
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```